# Get domain without subdomain in javascript

Tags: javascript, subdomain

How can I get the domain without subdomain in JS without jQuery?

I saw a lot of solutions with split and regular expressions that doesn't work in all this cases:

- http:// subdomain.domain.com.br
- http:// subdomain.domaincom
- http:// www.domain.com
- http:// www.domain.com.br

The result may be: domain.com / domain.com.br

Comment: You can't do that with just a regex without a [list of all TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains).

Comment: The perfect solution without regx
.......................................  

    var hostname = "your url";
     var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
        var subdomain = parts.shift();
        var upperleveldomain = parts.join('.');
    
 To get only the second-level-domain, you might use
   
       
  

    var sndleveldomain = parts.slice(-2).join('.');

Comment: @ShailendraSharma i already see and test this "solution" but It doesn't work for **all** cases mentioned before